# Como carga mas información de un servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Lo que pretendo hacer es cargar automáticamente (con datos de mi base de datos) un combobox con el tipo de empresa y posteriormente cuando seleccione el tipo se cargue automáticamente el combobox con el tipo de empresa elegida, el detalle es que mi pagina principal es un render de un servlet que es el inicio de mi pagina.

este es mi servlet que trae datos de la empresa (nombre,id,img,descripcion) y los envio a index.

```
public class InicioController extends HttpServlet {


   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        conexion conn = new conexion();
        EmpresaDAO fun = new EmpresaDAO(conn);
        List<empresa> lista = new LinkedList<>();
        lista=fun.MostrarEmpresa("");
        conn.desconectar();
        request.setAttribute("empresas", lista);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

esta es mi pagina, pero como sabrán en el explorador tengo que poner el nombre del servlet para que muestre la información y no index.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${empresas}" var="empresa">
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal${empresa.getIdEmpresa()}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Detalles de la empresa-->
                            <h2>${empresa.getNombreE()}</h2>
                            <p class="item-intro text-muted">${empresa.getDireccion()}</p>
                            <img src="imgE?idE=${empresa.getIdEmpresa()}" class="img-responsive imgEM" alt="">
                            <p>${empresa.getTexto()}</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Ver Perfil</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>

<div class="" style="width:100%; background-color:#151515; padding: 12px 20px;">
                <form action="" method="">          
                    <select ></select>
```

**aqui es donde quiero que se cargue en conjunto con lo que ya cargo de mi servlet**

```
<select ></select>              
                <button style="padding: 12px 10px; background-color: #133D4B; border: none; border-radius: 8px;">Buscar Linea</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```